# SharePoint 365 / Office 365 helpdesk template

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, sharepoint-2010

I want to use my current Sharepoint 365 for handling helpdesk tickets.  I want a really basic helpdesk utility.

I tried to install some applications templates and I couldn't. I found that Office 365 does not support application templates (am I right?)

I tried to install the [help desk template here](http://www.alentus.com/Sharepoint2010Templates/) and also the [Help Desk here](http://www.techsolutions.net/SharePointSolutions.aspx), but I didn't find a way.

I've seen that there is a [commercial app](http://www.assistmyteam.net/IssueTrackerSP/), but I'm interested in checking some other options (specially free options).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had no problems with installing SharePoint Foundation templates from [alentus.com](http://www.alentus.com) to Office365 Sharepoint.

### Step by step

1. Download your template.
2. Go to your Office365 portal site settings.
3. Navigate to `Galeries` -> `Solutions`.
4. On the `Solutions` tab, click `Upload solution`.
5. Follow the steps on the wizard and upload the `wsp` template.
6. Finally either through portal site settings or Sharepoint Designer create new site with your Helpdesk template.